# Problema para descargar mas de un archivo desde un servidor FTP con c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para descargar archivos desde un servidor FTP
Lo que necesito es descargar TODOS los archivos dentro del directorio, tengo un método pero solo me descarga un archivo, Este es mi método 1ro listo los archivos y la idea es descargarlos todos

```
public void DescargarComprobantes()
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://service/");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "pass");

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        List<string> directories = new List<string>();

        string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            directories.Add(line);
            line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        }

        foreach (string file in directories)
        {
            FtpWebRequest requests = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://service/" + file);

            requests.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            requests.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "pass");

            FtpWebResponse responses = (FtpWebResponse)requests.GetResponse();

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                responses.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(stream);
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file);
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        streamReader.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

¿Saben de algún método para hacerlo? ya que este solo me descarga un archivo
De antemano Gracias y buen día!!!!

Comment: ¿Tienes los permisos para descargar los archivos?

Comment: @fredyfx pero solo me descarga un archivo cuando en la lista hay 4 archivos